# Hexadecimal representation of -24

Tags: binary

I'm trying to convert -24 to the hexadecimal representation but I always end up with a decimal of 8 which is incorrect.

Work:

-24 -> 24

24 in binary is: 11000
Now I take the two's complement: 11000 -> 00111 + 1 -> 01000
01000 is 8.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You'e acting like there are only $5$ bits in the representation.  There are, presumably, other leading $0$ bits that you have to flip.  If there actually are only $5$ bits, then what you've done is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I forgot to add the sign bit which would turn the answer to 101000 which is 40. 40 converted into hex is 0x18 which is correct.